# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index Pandas Merge

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two pandas dataframes. Here are what the dataframes' columns look like:

toi_data:

```
MultiIndex([(    'Player',),
            (       'Pos',),
            (     'Shift',),
            (        'GP',),
            (    'EV TOI',),
            ('EV CF% Rel',),
            (  'EV GF/60',),
            (  'EV GA/60',),
            (    'PP TOI',),
            ('PP CF% Rel',),
            (  'PP GF/60',),
            (  'PP GA/60',),
            (    'SH TOI',),
            ('SH CF% Rel',),
            (  'SH GF/60',),
            (  'SH GA/60',),
            (      'Year',),
            (      'Team',)],
           )
```

new_df:

```
Index(['Player', 'Team', 'Year', 'Age', 'Pos', 'Country', 'Ht', 'Wt',
       'Birth Date', 'Draft', 'S/C', 'Salary', 'Summary', 'GP', 'G', 'A',
       'PTS', '+/-', 'PIM', 'EV', 'PP', 'SH', 'GW', 'EV.1', 'PP.1', 'SH.1',
       'S', 'S%', 'TOI', 'ATOI', 'OPS', 'DPS', 'PS', 'BLK', 'HIT', 'FOW',
       'FOL', 'FO%'],
      dtype='object')
```

Here is the code where I am trying to merge the two:

```
df2 = pd.merge(df1, toi_data, on=['Player', 'Team', 'Year'])
```

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

So my thought is that the toi_data dataframe is causing the error to be thrown. I've tried using .unstack() and reset_index(inplace=True) to convert the Multi-Index, but neither worked. Any ideas on how I can resolve this error? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You probably want to do `toi_data.columns = toi_data.columns.drop_level(1)` prior to the merge. That MultiIndex is superfluous, so probably best to figure out why it was created in the first place and fix it there.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @ALollz, unfortunately when I tried the drop_level call I got this error ```IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 levels, not 2```. This really confuses me because of the first error calling the DF a MultiIndex but this error saying it only has 1 level...

Comment: Hmmm. Let me think about why that's the case and why I can't remove it. `toi_data.columns = toi_data.columns.get_level_values(0)` should be the better alternative in this case to flatten the MultiIndex.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @ALollz . get_level_values(0) worked! Thank you so much!